# How to pass viewbag information from Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am moving my crud operations from the controller into a repository.

How can I pass the viewbag information from the repository to the controller and then to the view?

**My Controller calls PopulateAssigneUserData in the repository**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WWW.Models;
using WWW.DAL;
using WWW.ViewModels;

namespace WWW.Controllers
{ 
    public class RolesController : Controller
    {
        private Iaspnet_RolesRepository aspnet_RolesRepository;

        public RolesController()
        {
            this.aspnet_RolesRepository = new Aspnet_RolesRepository(new WorldofWarCraftContext());
        }

        public RolesController(Iaspnet_RolesRepository aspnet_RolesRepository)
        {
            this.aspnet_RolesRepository = aspnet_RolesRepository;
        }


        //
        // GET: /Roles/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
        {
            aspnet_Roles aspnet_Role = db.aspnet_Roless        
            .Include(i => i.aspnet_User)
            .Where(i => i.RoleId == id)
            .Single();

            PopulateAssigneUserData(aspnet_Role);
            return View(aspnet_Role);
        }
```

My Repository has the code that used to live in the controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using WWW.Models;
using WWW.ViewModels;

namespace WWW.DAL
{
    public class Aspnet_RolesRepository : Iaspnet_RolesRepository, Iaspnet_UsersRepository , IDisposable
    {
        private WorldofWarCraftContext context;

        public Aspnet_RolesRepository(WorldofWarCraftContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<aspnet_Roles> GetRoles()
        {
            return context.aspnet_Roless.ToList();
        }

        public aspnet_Roles GetRolesByID(Guid id)
        {
            return context.aspnet_Roless.Find(id);
        }


        private void PopulateAssigneUserData(aspnet_Roles aspnet_Role)
        {
            var allUsers = context.aspnet_Users;
            var rolesUsers = new HashSet<Guid>(aspnet_Role.aspnet_User.Select(c => c.UserId));
            var viewModel = new List<AssigneUserData>();
            foreach (var User in allUsers)
            {
                viewModel.Add(new AssigneUserData
                {
                    UserId = User.UserId,
                    UserName = User.UserName,
                    Assigned = rolesUsers.Contains(User.UserId)
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Users = viewModel;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the responsibilities here. A repository should not work with view models and ViewBag. A repository should return domain models. It is the controller responsibility to map those domain models to view models and pass those view models to the view. This `PopulateAssigneUserData` method should not live in your repository. In your repository you should have a method that returns an `aspnet_Role` instance given an id (the code that you currently have in your Edit action).

Comment: Are you saying that I should leave that piece of code in the controller?

Comment: Yes, you have mixed things up. The repository should contain the domain model logic (that is currently in your controller). You have done exactly the inverse of what it should be done. A repository should have absolutely no notion of ViewBag or view models at all. A repository represents your data access layer.